# Angular Routing in Django

Tags: angularjs, django, angular-routing

I am new to Angular JS and trying to implement routing in a Django App.
My Html code is:-

```
 <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" ng-app="QuizRouting">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/page1">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

My JS code is :-

```
var app = angular.module('QuizRouting',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("quiz/page1", {
            templateUrl: "/quiz/templates/quiz/page1.html"
        });
});
```

I have included all the prerequisites for Angular and angular routing. But on clicking on the page 1 link the required template is not rendered.

this is the page1.html:-

```
<div>
    <h1>Its Working!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had incorrect `href` on **Page 1** anchor. You should correct it to below.

```
<li><a href="#/page1">Page 1</a></li>
```

And in .when also

```
.when('/page1', ....)
```

Comment: No. The base page I render is at  'localhost:8000/quiz/'

Comment: so I think the link is proper

Comment: @AniruddhaBhondwe No, it isn't. check updated, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You send a get request for /quiz/templates/quiz/page1.html, but django doesn't recognize this path.
Try putting your pages in quiz/static/quiz/pages and change

```
templateUrl: "/quiz/templates/quiz/page1.html"
```

to

```
templateUrl: "/quiz/static/quiz/pages/page1.html"
```